# Can't get my results back from recursion in Prolog after reaching base case

Tags: recursion, prolog, reporting, read-eval-print-loop

I'm trying to get how Prolog recursion works. For some reason after reaching base case it unwinds all the results back. Here is the code:

```
makeMove([0 | Tail], List).
makeMove([Head | Tail], List) :-
    Head1 is Head - 1,
    makeMove([Head1 | Tail], [[Head1 | Tail] | List]).

move(InputList, Output) :-
    makeMove(InputList, Output).
```

What I'm trying to do here is to generate the list of lists that can be formed by subtracting 1 from the first element of the input List until it's 0.
Here's the stack trace:

```
[trace]  ?- 
|    move([3,4,5], X).
   Call: (8) move([3, 4, 5], _23538) ? creep
   Call: (9) makeMove([3, 4, 5], _23538) ? creep
   Call: (10) _23792 is 3+ -1 ? creep
   Exit: (10) 2 is 3+ -1 ? creep
   Call: (10) makeMove([2, 4, 5], [[2, 4, 5]|_23538]) ? creep
   Call: (11) _23816 is 2+ -1 ? creep
   Exit: (11) 1 is 2+ -1 ? creep
   Call: (11) makeMove([1, 4, 5], [[1, 4, 5], [2, 4, 5]|_23538]) ? creep
   Call: (12) _23840 is 1+ -1 ? creep
   Exit: (12) 0 is 1+ -1 ? creep
   Call: (12) makeMove([0, 4, 5], [[0, 4, 5], [1, 4, 5], [2, 4, 5]|_23538]) ? creep
   Exit: (12) makeMove([0, 4, 5], [[0, 4, 5], [1, 4, 5], [2, 4, 5]|_23538]) ? creep
   Exit: (11) makeMove([1, 4, 5], [[1, 4, 5], [2, 4, 5]|_23538]) ? creep
   Exit: (10) makeMove([2, 4, 5], [[2, 4, 5]|_23538]) ? creep
   Exit: (9) makeMove([3, 4, 5], _23538) ? creep
   Exit: (8) move([3, 4, 5], _23538) ? creep
true
```

Comment: "unwinds all the results back" - this is what Prolog is specifically designed to do - it's called "back-tracking".

Comment: @Enigmativity that's not what's actually happening here. It's just a recursive call without a base case to bind the computed state.

Comment: @DanielLyons - Yes, but it is back-tracking still.

Comment: @Enigmativity not when the first proof has been constructed, there's no backtracking yet, then.

Comment: @WillNess: Why these tags?

Comment: @false I thought they reflected the question, getting the result back from recursion; seeing them reported at the REPL...

Comment: @WillNess: who will search for tag [result]  etc.

Comment: @WillNess: But that's not their purpose...

Comment: @Will: The second phrase reads: "Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories." That certainly does not apply to the tags you gave: Repl was a misunderstanding by OP, result is no such category, and reporting is too generic.

Comment: @Will: Can you identify on SO one question were [result] or [reporting] does not apply in the same way as it applies to this question? I doubt there is any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of Output in the innermost call is the value of the previous call with some stuff put on it, but Prolog variables are not mutable. What you have is an intermediate state. To obtain it from the last result, you need a third parameter:

```
makeMove([0 | Tail], Result, Result).

makeMove([Head | Tail], List, Result) :-
    Head1 is Head - 1,
    makeMove([Head1 | Tail], [[Head1 | Tail] | List], Result).

move(InputList, Output) :-
    makeMove(InputList, [], Output).
```

This is not your only issue, but this should get you over the hump.

Answer (score 3):

In the event of successfully proving a query it was given, Prolog reports back to us all the free variables that were present in the query. For instance, proving

```
?- move([3,4,5], X).
```

if successful (and it will be), will report back to us the value now held by `X`.

Which will be ... still just `X`, since you do nothing with it.

Your proof adds stuff on top of `X` as it proceeds, but then when the final case is reached all this stuff is not bound to anything reachable from the top query. `X` serves as input, and there's no output recorded anywhere.

To get this "output", the solution given in Daniel's answer is usually employed -- another, third argument is given to the query, is passed unchanged all along, and is only bound at the very deepest clause reached when the full solution has been built.

At this point Prolog will pause, and report back to us all the free variables that we supplied in the query. One of which will be that one that was just set to refer to the full solution just built.